# Set labelindent for basedescript (mdwlist)

Tags: labels, description

I would like to integrate a multiline label for a description environment. Therefor, I already found out that the package mdwlist could do the job for me.

I almost got the result I want, except for the labelindent. Anybody who knows the mdwlist way of putting the label (and following text) with a labelindent?

The result with a standard description environment looks like this:

```
\begin{description}[labelindent=0.5cm,labelwidth=4cm,leftmargin=!]%
    \item [{\parbox[t]{4cm}{Boutons du vibreur\\en bas}}] L'opération du vibreur en bas est fait par les boutons situés sur le cabinet électrique du vibreur.
    \item [Boutons du système de distribution] Les commandes de base du système de distribution peuvent être données par 2 stations de boutons, une de chaque côté de la machine.
    \item [Écran Beckhoff] Le contrôle de l'installation, à l'exception de la peseuse, est fait par cet écran. Il a le but de visualiser le fonctionnement et de commander le système de distribution.
    \item [Écran Ishida] La peseuse est commandée par cet écran séparé.
\end{description}
```

[image]

You can see that the label is too long, so I tried using mdwlist. I want to keep the labelindent=0.5cm but don't know how to do this...

```
\usepackage{mdwlist}

\begin{basedescript}{\desclabelwidth{4cm} \desclabelstyle{\multilinelabel}}
    \item [Boutons du vibreur en bas] L'opération du vibreur en bas est fait par les boutons situés sur le cabinet électrique du vibreur.
    \item [Boutons du système de distribution] Les commandes de base du système de distribution peuvent être données par 2 stations de boutons, une de chaque côté de la machine.
    \item [Écran Beckhoff] Le contrôle de l'installation, à l'exception de la peseuse, est fait par cet écran. Il a le but de visualiser le fonctionnement et de commander le système de distribution.
    \item [Écran Ishida] La peseuse est commandée par cet écran séparé.
\end{basedescript}
```

[image]

Comment: As always on this site please post a full but minimal example instead of sniplets like this. Then the code is much easier to test. One question, why mdwlist and not enumitem? Especially since mdwlist has not been updated since 1996!!

Comment: The `mdwlist` package has been unmaintained for 24 years. Try `enumitem`.

Comment: I found another way [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462549/two-line-labels-in-the-description-items)